# Ключи-числа становятся строками в сессии django

Tags: python, django

Пытаюсь реализовать корзину с товарами для интернет магазина на django. Задача такая: хранить в сессиях ид товаров и их количество. Если товар уже есть в корзине, то количество приплюсовываем к старому количеству (добавление).

```
def post(self, request, **kwargs):
    post = request.POST
    item_id = int(post.get('id'))
    count = int(post.get('count'))
    if 'cart' not in request.session:
        request.session['cart'] = {}
    if item_id not in request.session['cart']:
        request.session['cart'][item_id] = count
    else:
        old = int(request.session['cart'][item_id])
        request.session['cart'][item_id] = old + count

    print(request.session['cart'])
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'result': 'success'}))
```

Проблема в том, что при добавлении существующего товара один из id превращается из числа в строку, из за чего в корзину добавляется уже существующий товар. Выглядит это следующим образом:

```
{4: 1, u'4': 1} #4 - id товара, 1 - его количество
```

В чем проблема?

Comment: Можете добавить что-то типа `print('before', request.session['cart'])` перед строчкой `if item_id not in request.session['cart']`? Пока на первый взгляд я ошибок не вижу (кроме, скажем так, стилистических, но об этом потом)

Comment: Ну или я может ещё предположу, что в какой-то старой версии кода вы забыли сделать `int(..)`, потом это исправили, а сессию почистить забыли, и этот `u'4'` возможно остался от старой версии кода

Comment: @andreymal `('before', {})
{4: 1}
[14/Sep/2017 13:22:09] "POST /ajax/addtocart/ HTTP/1.1" 200 20
('before', {u'4': 1})
{4: 3, u'4': 1}`

Comment: Ага, понял, сейчас напишу ответ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это такая особенность хранения данных сессии.

Чтобы сохранить данные, нужно те Python-объекты, которые вы создаёте (словарь с числами) как-то сконвертировать в байты для хранения их в базе данных (или в cookies, зависит от настроек). Это называется сериализацией.

По умолчанию Django сериализует данные сессии в JSON. Однако JSON поддерживает только строковые ключи для словарей, поэтому ваше число-ключ `4` при сохранении сессии преобразуется в unicode-строку `u'4'`, которые вы и видите в `print` в следующем запросе.

Есть два варианта, что делать:

- смириться с этим. Просто используйте строку `item_id = post.get('id')` (вам бы надо дописать валидацию всех входных данных, но это не по теме вопроса) и преобразуйте эту строку в число, только когда уж совсем приспичит;
- заменить сериализатор на другой. Django из коробки также умеет сериализовать объекты с помощью pickle, у которого нет почти никаких ограничений, и ключи-числа должны остаться числами. Для этого пропишите в настройках проекта (обычно `settings.py`):

  ```
  SESSION_SERIALIZER = 'django.contrib.sessions.serializers.PickleSerializer'
  ```

Рекомендую попутно почитать [документацию про сессии](https://djbook.ru/rel1.8/topics/http/sessions.html), там рассматриваются некоторые вопросы безопасности.